# How to set the codes to check If the user has signed in before, start the MainActivity.class, else the StartActivity.class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

/**
 * Loading screen activity
 */
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    Handler handler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if ( currentUser != null ) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                }
        },3000);

    }
}
```

I did this code

```
if ( currentUser != null ) {
```

But the above code didn't seem to work, it always run this StartActivity.class

Unless the currentUser function is not working

Comment: What is it that's supposed to change `currentUser` to something other than its initial default value of null?

Comment: The right solution was given by Lil Mpesa. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize **FirebaseAuth** to get the credentials with **FirebaseUser** variable.

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseUser currentUser;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

private Handler handler;

/*
* Checks if user is logged in & return true or false value
*/
public boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    
    handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Use the value to fire login or start activity
            if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
                /*
                * User is logged in (Start MainActivity)
                */
                
            } else {
                /*
                * User doesn't exist (Log in / Create Account if needed)
                */
            }
        }
    },3000);
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to initialize your `currentUser` variable. From the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```